# beautiful soup printing nothing

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to have beautiful soup pull info from a website and have it print just in the console. When it does it, its printing `[]` and i have no clue how to fix it.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
mlsspan = soup.find_all("td.d1m8")
print(mlsspan)
```

html being pulled

```
<td class="d1m8">
    <span class="d1m1">
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('m_DisplayCore','Redisplay|188,,0')">A11033427</a>
    </span>
</td>
```

I can't give the website because its password protected.

I'm trying to get the `A11033427` from the `<a>` tag.

i've also tried

```
mlsspan = soup.find_all("td.d1m1")
```

Comment: Try this, `soup.find_all('td', attrs={"class":"d1m8"})`, that's how you pull items of a certain class in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: In addition. the page might be loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.find_all` use `.select_one`/`.select`. `.find_all` doesn't accept CSS selectors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<td class="d1m8">
    <span class="d1m1">
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('m_DisplayCore','Redisplay|188,,0')">A11033427</a>
    </span>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one("td.d1m8 a").text)
```

Prints:

```
A11033427
```

Comment: Upvoted. You always answer just a few seconds before me :-)

Comment: i tested this by itself and yes it works with the html as ```html_doc```  but, when i put it into my script where it scrapes the site source. i get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\classes\scrape.py", line 66, in <module>
    print(soup.select_one("td.d1m8 a").text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'``` as a error

Comment: @reggiejones do `print(soup)` and verify if the tags are really there. If not, the tags are injected by Javascript and other methods must be used (`selenium`, ajax etc.)

Comment: @andrejkesely How would you write it in ```selenium``` i tried ```mlsnum = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[@class='d1m8'")``` but i dont think i wrote it right?

Comment: @reggiejones You can use the same CSS selector: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.d1m8 a")`